# Uploading a BitmapImage as JSON post for Windows Runtime apps

Tags: c#, json, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I've got a `BitmapImage` defined as:

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://link.com/image.jpg"));
```

Now, I need to encode the image as `Base64` and then do a POST as `JSON`. I haven't found many guides on this, and when I do, it uses Silverlight or .NET libraries that aren't available for windows store development, which I think uses WinRT. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your scenario you might be able to use the `UriSource` from the `BitmapImage` to read the image again and convert it to `Base64` string:

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("https://i.stack.imgur.com/830Ke.jpg?s=128&g=1"));

RandomAccessStreamReference rasr = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(bitmapImage.UriSource);
var streamWithContent = await rasr.OpenReadAsync();

byte[] buffer = new byte[streamWithContent.Size];
await streamWithContent.ReadAsync(buffer.AsBuffer(), (uint)streamWithContent.Size, InputStreamOptions.None);

string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
```

It seems if you are doing a Windows Store App prior to Windows 8.1 Update 1 you have to manually add the correct namespace for the [AsBuffer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh598390.aspx) extension to work, so try add this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
```

Comment: `buffer` doesn't have the method `AsBuffer`.

Comment: @SunnySydeUp Oh yes, you are correct, it is not available for Windows 8.0/Windows 8.1 apps. It became available with the very recent Universal Store apps for Windows 8.1 Update 1. I will take a look at it again.

Comment: @SunnySydeUp I have update the code, AsBuffer() should according to the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh598390.aspx) Work since Windows 8, but you need to manually add the namespace, see the updated answer.